# Python Tor sharing socket port with local network

Tags: python, tor

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to share my tor connection with another pc in my network.I create Tor using expert bundle and torrc file looks like this.

```
# Where data will be stored?
DataDirectory C:\Users\someuser\Tor\TorData\data\10002

# Countdown time before exit
ShutdownWaitLength 5

# Where to write PID
PidFile C:\Users\someuser\Tor\TorData\data\10002\pid

# Communication ports
SocksPort xx.xxx.xxx.xx:10002
ControlPort xx.xxx.xxx.xx:10003

# Authentication of Tor
CookieAuthentication 1

# GeoIP file paths?
GeoIPFile C:\Users\someuser\Tor\Data\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\someuser\Tor\Data\Tor\geoip6

SocksListenAddress xx.xxx.xxx.xx
SocksPolicy accept xx.xxx.xxx.xx/24
```

So now I'm trying to use that same tor connection from another pc like this.

```
import requests

ses = requests.session()
ses.proxies = {'http': '{0}{1}:{2}'.format('socks5://','xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 10002),
            'https': '{0}{1}:{2}'.format('socks5://','xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 10002)}

r = ses.get('some http webpage')
print r.content
```

I did check firewall settings that is ok. Over stem I can connect to control port. But dunno why SockPort doesn't pass.

error that im geting no matter the veriso of interpeter is

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\socks.py", line 73, in _new_conn
    conn = socks.create_connection(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that is is because of differance in  python interperter after all. It must run in python 3 both sides and it will work like a charm.

I hope someone will help torrc configuration.